# prove a matrix that is positive definite based on distance between balls and the radius of the balls

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have n balls(with radius $R$), and the distance between ball $i$ and ball $j$ is $d_{ij}$. I define an $n\times n$ matrix, with 1 on the diagonal, and $\frac{R}{d_{ij}}$ for the other elements. So the restriction is that $2R<d_{ij}$ and $d_{ij},d_{jk},d_{ki}$ can form a triangle.

Can we prove this matrix is positive definite?

Comment: What are $d_{i},d_j,d_k$?

Comment: Sorry! I correct the typo. They should be $d_{ij}$...

Comment: Unless you  have any other natural restrications on $d_{ij}$ I am afraid this statement is wrong. The matrix does not have to be positive definite

Comment: Actually may be I am wrong.